# ActionLink image hover button effect with mouse event

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, css, html.actionlink

I want to create button effect i.e. mouse_over, mouse_leave and mouse_click using the jQuery. I have link written in ActionLink in mvc 4 using visual studio 2012. so i want to change image with slightly bigger image and when mouse leave, it go back to original image and some kind of effect when link is click...

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "index1", "Home","index1", new {id="a1", @class="dashboard_function_icons"})

@Html.ActionLink(" ", "index2", "Home","index2", new {id="a2", @class = "dashboard_function_icons"})

@Html.ActionLink(" ", "index3", "Home","index3", new {id="a3", @class = "dashboard_function_icons"})

CSS CODE
---------
.dashboard_function_icons {

   display:block;
   height: 15px;
   width: 20px;
   padding-left: 80px;
   padding-bottom: 80px;
   margin-top:10px;
   margin-left:10px;
   float:left;
}

  #a1 {
    background: url("../Images/people.png") no-repeat;
  }

  #a2 {
    background: url("../Images/ball.png") no-repeat;
  }

  #a3 {
    background: url("../Images/save.png") no-repeat;
    }

 jQuery
 -------
 $(".dashboard_function_icons").hover(
        function () { $(this).},
        function () { $(this).;});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`.addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`.removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) functions inside your hover callbacks.

Comment: is there any example that i can follow, i am struggling to grasp of how to do that ... many thanks in advanced!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that just using CSS with :hover pseudo-class and a sprite image, and just moving the sprite image in the background with css. see [this article](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)